# How can I use different properties for the dropdown and the cell contents of a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have the following class:

```
public class Zone {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Formatted {get;set;}
}
```

with the following `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ZoneID}" DisplayMemberPath="Formatted" SelectedValuePath="ZoneID" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and I am using a `List<Zone>` as the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
((DataGridComboBoxColumn)dg.Columns[0]).ItemsSource = new List<Zone> {
    new Zone {ID=0,Name="Zone0",Formatted="Zone0 - Formatted"},
    new Zone {ID=1,Name="Zone1",Formatted="Zone1 - Formatted"},
    new Zone {ID=2,Name="Zone2",Formatted="Zone2 - Formatted"},
    new Zone {ID=3,Name="Zone3",Formatted="Zone3 - Formatted"},
    new Zone {ID=4,Name="Zone4",Formatted="Zone4 - Formatted"}
};
```

Setting `DisplayMemberPath="Formatted"` has two effects:

1. The cell contents contain the value of the `Formatted` property
2. The dropdown uses `Formatted` to generate the dropdown items.

[image: DisplayMemberPath="Formatted] [image: DisplayMemberPath="Name"]

How can I have the cell contents use the `Name` property, while the dropdown uses the `Formatted` property?

Comment: Does a ComboBox behave differently than a DataGridComboBoxColumn?  I think that is referred to as the SelectionBox.

Comment: @Blam Do you mean the [Telerik UI control](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radcombobox-overview.html), which has a [`SelectionBoxTemplate`](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radcombobox-populating-with-data-selectionbox.html) property? The standard [DataGridComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes no mention of something like that.

Comment: Really? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.selectionboxitemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, but apparently not in the DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution without overriding the whole template by using a DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class ComboBoxTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate BoxTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate ListTemplate { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    var test = container;

    while (test != null)
    {
      if (test is ComboBox)
      {
        return BoxTemplate;
      }

      if (test is ComboBoxItem)
      {
        return ListTemplate;
      }

      test = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(test);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Box">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="List">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Formatted}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Selector:ComboBoxTemplateSelector x:Key="Selector" 
          BoxTemplate="{StaticResource Box}" ListTemplate="{StaticResource List}" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CmbTemplate">
      <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Zone}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Values, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.Resources>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource CmbTemplate}">
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I would have preferred to use a DataGridComboBoxColumn, but I prefer this answer for its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If a DatagridTemplateColumn is also ok, you can do the following:

- Copy the original template from http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/ms752094%28v=vs.100%29.aspx 
  into the resources
- Replace the line 
  `<ContentPresenter />`
  (line 6 from the bottom of the template) with 
  `<Label Content="{Binding Formatted}" />`
- Change the DatagridComboBoxColumn to DatagridTemplateColumn containing a combobox